# GetValue method of JSlider does not return current value?

Tags: java, jslider

I use JSlider in my project. And in somewhere I need to get the value of slider but getValue() method does not return the current slider value. It always returns the default value.

Here is the related part of my code:

```
 this.slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            // This two lines below are about Cytoscape framework. I am taking a column of a table and convert it to List<String>. There are not doing anything about slider.
            CyColumn timeColumn = table.getColumn("startTime"); // Getting start time column
            List<String> timeList = filter.getTimeFromColumn(timeColumn); // Gets value of start time column without null values
            // I printed out slider.getValue() value and it returns default slider value all the time.
            sliderLabel.setText(timeList.get(slider.getValue()));
        }
    });
```

In another part of my code, I need to change the min and max values of the slider. For that, I use the code below:

```
public void reCreateSlider(){
    // Activity size returns correct.
    ArrayList<CyNode> activities = filter.FilterRowByNodeType("activity", "nodeType");
    this.slider = new JSlider(0, activities.size());
}
```

Why slider.getValue() returns default value all the time? Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just change the reCreateSlider() method like below and it worked.

```
public void reCreateSlider(){
// Activity size returns correct.
ArrayList<CyNode> activities = filter.FilterRowByNodeType("activity", "nodeType");
slider.setMinimum(0);
slider.setMaximum(activities.size());
}
```

If anyone has the same problem, can do this way.